# Remove [ecma] tag

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request

All questions with the [ecma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecma) tag should be retagged with [ecmascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript).

Comment: ECMA has issued many standards, the .NET ones are notable.  ECMAscript is just one of them.  Leans to the left of a meta-tag, burnination seems appropriate.  The [iso] tag has similar problems.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes indeed, However, all the questions I've seen refer to ECMAScript, just as the tag wiki does. I'm not suggesting a synonym :-)

Comment: The tag is still there and is still being used to mean “ECMAScript”. The script below may have helped remove the tag from a few questions back in 2015, but now it has 174 questions. The tag should ideally be blocklisted since questions about standards organizations are not about programming, thus off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now went over the list and, with the help of the following little userscript, removed/replaced all [ecma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecma) tags on questions that target the scripting language.

```
// works in list views, so you don't need to open the posts manually
var replace = {
    "ecma": "ecmascript"
};
$("div.question-summary").each(function() {
    var postid = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    var tags = $("a.post-tag", this).map(function() {
        var tag = (this.href.match(/\/questions\/tagged\/(.+)/) || {})[1];
        // console.log(postid, tag);
        if (tag && tag in replace)
            $(this).after(" (", $("<a>", {text:"Replace by "+replace[tag]}).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post("/posts/"+postid+"/edit-tags", {
                    tagnames: tags.map(function(x) { return x==tag ? replace[x] : x }).join(" "),
                    fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey
                }).then(function(res) {
                    if (!res.success)
                        return $.Deferred().reject(res);
                    e.target.style.color = "green";
                }).then(null, function(err) {
                    e.target.style.color = "red";
                    e.target.textContent = err;
                });
            }), ")");
        return tag;
    }).get();
});
```

Edited about 100 questions in less than 20 minutes :-)

Comment: I'm all for userscripts (I have a few burnination scripts of my own that I consider too powerful/useful to use for myself sometimes), but I'm hesitant to share them for that reason. This could easily be abused (although I'd hope anyone with edit privileges wouldn't want to), but I don't want to discourage you from sharing it - it's just something to consider. Usage of scripts to burninate/retag also violates [Shog's recommendation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/258672) for burnination, but those guidelines are just a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I could've written an auto-burninator as well, but then opted for a "one click per question" solution, which is not that harmful :-) I still do hope that my activity raised a flag somewhere to be investigated. Where does Shog mention scripts in his answer?

Comment: He doesn't, but auto-stripping tags pretty much means that you won't fix up each one.