# What are [counters]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

It looks like [counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counters) are things that count some things somehow, or maybe just change value over time or something, but there's no tag wiki and I seriously doubt the 123 questions tagged with this are getting anything out of it.

Comment: The [tag:counters] tag is pretty broad right now (based on the questions), even without the wiki.

Comment: Some of them are about performance counters.  We have a [performancecounter] tag; its wiki says it's about a .NET class, but there's some general performance counter usage there too.

Comment: Retagged and edited about 30 posts, have fun with the rest. (You might want to include [tag:counter] too.) And @JeffreyBosboom, that tag-wiki is simply wrong, even if whoever made it never looked and only knew .net...

Comment: @Deduplicator, that seems to be a very general problem—people assume some word only means a certain thing in their personal favorite language.

Comment: Yes. Well, I made a quick-fix of that tag-wiki, correcting the scope but only adding a miniscule amount of information.

Comment: I think I'll write a wiki of my own opinion and see if someone likes it.

Answer (score 17):

The tag is overly ambiguous, had no tag wiki, and added nothing to any of the questions that it decorated.

It seems to be another case of "I don't know what to put in the tag field, so I'll just type words in my title and see what pops up."

All 123 questions have been retagged, and it has been burninated.

[image: The great Burninator]

Comment: AstroCB, you seem to do burninate really fast. Do you have any userscripts or something to make it faster? (also, nice great burinator)

Comment: @JZL003 [I do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284523/remove-ecma-tag/284530#comment147570_284530). However, I try to avoid using them as much as possible, and I use them in conjunction with [the SE Editor's Toolkit](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit) to ensure that the posts receive proper treatment as per Shog's [burnination guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).